# Pull information based on selection

Tags: php, javascript, forms, variables, input

I have a form on one page and on submit it goes to a form on another. I would like to make a variable so it pulls the number so it can be POSTed on the form.

```
<!---these are the thumbs--->
<a id="155a" class="ThumbClick"href="#"><img src="images/thumb/5032.jpg" /></a>
<a id="156a" class="ThumbClick"href="#"><img src="images/thumb/5033.jpg" /></a>             
<a id="157a" class="ThumbClick"href="#"><img src="images/thumb/5034.jpg" /></a>

<!--these represent the number shown when thumb is clicked and the go to other form--->
<div id="call-to-action">
<h2 id="155c" class="image-num">5032</h2>
<h2 id="156c" class="image-num">5033</h2>
<h2 id="157c" class="image-num">5034</h2>
<form  id="quote" method="post" action="quote.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="cat" value="Revision Door" />
    <input type="hidden" name="des" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Get A Quote" />
</form>
</div>

<!---these represent the full size image--->
<img id="155b" class="hide1" src="images/fullsize/5032.jpg" />
<img id="156b" class="hide1" src="images/fullsize/5033.jpg" />              
<img id="157b" class="hide1" src="images/fullsize/5034.jpg" />



<!--this is the jquery that makes it all work--->
$(function () {
    $('.ThumbClick').click(function (eb) {
        var $idb = this.id.replace('a', 'b');

        eb.preventDefault();
        $('.show,#' + $idb).toggleClass('show');
    });
    $('.ThumbClick').click(function (ec) {
        var $idc = this.id.replace('a', 'c');

        ec.preventDefault();
        $('#' + $idc).toggleClass('show');
    });
    $('.ThumbClick').click(function () {
        $('#call-to-action').addClass('show');
    });
});
```

The `.image-num` corresponds to an image and when a thumb is clicked it displays the text (i.e. 5033) I need to POST the (i.e. 5033) on the form and not the id.

Comment: So you want it so that whichever `<h2>` is clicked on the number inside of it is submitted with the form? Also are you using/able to use jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your jQuery to add the following:

```
$(function () {
    $('.ThumbClick').click(function (eb) {
        var $idb = this.id.replace('a', 'b');

        eb.preventDefault();
        $('.show,#' + $idb).toggleClass('show');
    });
    $('.ThumbClick').click(function (ec) {
        var $idc = this.id.replace('a', 'c');

        ec.preventDefault();
        $('#' + $idc).toggleClass('show');
        $('input[name="des"]').val($('#'+ $idc).html()); // <- Add Me
    });
    $('.ThumbClick').click(function () {
        $('#call-to-action').addClass('show');
    });
});
```

You can also condense all of this into one `.click()` function, there's no need to have 3.

```
$(function () {
    $('.ThumbClick').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $idb = this.id.replace('a', 'b');
        $('.show,#' + $idb).toggleClass('show');

        var $idc = this.id.replace('a', 'c');
        $('#' + $idc).toggleClass('show');
        $('input[name="des"]').val($('#'+ $idc).html()); // <- Add Me

        $('#call-to-action').addClass('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: I need the value of the second hidden input reflect the number shown within the h2 tags. the way i have it set up now then thumb1 is clicked pic1 is shown and image-num1 shows and if thumb2 then pic2 and image-num2 shows and so on.

Comment: @user2517352 How are thumb1, thumb2, etc related to the `<h2>` elements containing the numbers? Also can you please edit the code for thumb1, thumb2, etc into your question?

Comment: It did not work plus it made my     #call-to-action div not appear.

Comment: @user2517352 I made an error in my function naming, my bad. See my edit.